# Finding the relative shift and rotation that gives the maximum overlap for two point-clouds

Tags: optimization, computer-vision, point-clouds

I have two pointclouds in a 3D euclidean space, and I want to find the relative rotation and translation between the two pointclouds that gives the most overlap (or in other words, that minimizes the Wasserstein Distance, or any other optimal-transport metric, between the pointclouds).

I know that for translation one would simply shift the "center of mass". However rotation doesn't seem very intuitive to me.

What I have tried:

My approach was to compute the inertia tensor and rotate the point clouds to align their principal axes. However this is numerically unstable for pointclouds with high degrees of symmetry.

Comment: There’s so much scientific literature on this topic: https://www.google.com/search?q=rigid+point+set+registration Have you looked into any of it? I mean even Wikipedia has a nice summary on the topic!

Comment: Thanks so much, I didn't even know what to look for! This already helps a lot.